# How do I pick a custom font in Lyx?

Tags: lyx, font-faces

How do I pick a custom font using LyX? All I see are options to pick Roman/Serif/Typewriter and then a few preset faces. I have hundreds of fonts on my system and want to be able to use them.

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: Yes, Windows Vista.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fonts on your system are separate from LaTex, which Lyx is just a front end for.  Lyx can only help you select the [LaTex fonts](http://web.image.ufl.edu/help/latex/fonts.shtml) that are installed.  Odds are you had Lyx install MiKTex for you when you installed Lyx, so checkout the [MiKTex font install guide](http://miktex.org/packages/fontinstallationguide)

Comment: Can't LyX work with XeLaTeX?

Comment: Yes, you can use just about anything, as long as LyX can invoke latex or latex2e,  but if you don't already have it installed, LyX will reach out and install MiKTeX for you.  See http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/lyx/lyx_latex_tex.htm

Comment: P.S. XeTeX is shipped with MiKTeX since version 2.7

Comment: http://miktex.org/packages/fontinstallationguide doesn't has the `fontinstallationguide`.pdf where should I get this?

Comment: @claws I would be concerned about my miktex install. You can get it from http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/fontinstallationguide.cab.  Download the file, extract the cab.  The pdf is in `texmf/doc/guides`